# Python CSV Boolean Logic

Tags: python, csv, boolean

I'm trying to compute inside a CSV file but I am running into this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "spambi.py", line 6, in <module>
spamwriter.writerow(['5'], x > 0)
TypeError: writerow() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

I don't want the CSV file to write down verbatim what I put down such as x > 0. What I want the CSV file to write is True. How could I get that done?

```
import csv

with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
            x = 0 
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter= ' ')
    spamwriter.writerow(['5'], x > 0)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam']
```

Comment: The problem is only that your boolean is outside of the list, try `['5', x > 0]`.

Comment: Thanks, now I wonder how to put it in the adjacent cell.

Comment: What do you mean "in the adjacent cell"? When I run `spamwriter.writerow(['5', 2 > 1])`, I get `5 True`. `5` is in the first cell, `True` is in the 2nd cell, and the cells are separated by a single `' '`.